# Timeseries resample

Tags: clojure, time-series, data-analysis

I have a dict, similar to the `{:datetime [unix-timestamp] :count [longs]}`.

There are an equal number of things in `:datetime` and `:count`.

`:datetime` not have specified interval, usually ticks data. I would like to resample the data so that they have a defined interval, eg 5 minutes, and sum up `:count` of the range.

example:

```
{
   :datetime [timestamp every minute] 
   :count [1 1 1 1 1. . .] 
}
```

resample it to

```
{
   :datetime [timestamp every 5 minutes] 
   :count [5 5 5 5 5 ...] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to take one element in five from the timestamp vector, and add groups of five counts from the counts vector. Something like this will do it:

```
(defn resample [m]
  (let [{dt :datetime ct :count} m
        newdt (map first (partition 5 dt))
        newct (map (partial apply +) (partition 5 ct))]
    {:datetime newdt
     :count newct}))
```

Comment: It works only if there is a specific interval. If I have data ticks, I can not use `partition`. Similarly, if I have gap in the data.

Comment: In that case you can do it in a `loop/recur` with an accumulator. It should be pretty trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something fancy, but possibly inefficient:

```clj
(defn resample-5 [{:keys [datetime count]}]
  (letfn [(floor-5 [dt] (- dt (mod dt (* 5 60 1000))))
          (sum-counts [[time pairs]]
                      [time (reduce + (map second pairs))])]
    (let [pairs (partition 2 (interleave datetime count))
          pair-groups (group-by #(floor-5 (first %)) pairs)
          sums (map sum-counts pair-groups)]
      {:datetime (map first sums)
       :count (map second sums)})))
```

Note how many operations it performs on the collection: `interleave`, `partition`, `group-by`, `map`+`reduce`, and again `map` twice.

And here's something much more efficient that only scans the collection once:

```clj
(defn resample-5 [{:keys [datetime count]}]
  (letfn [(add-tick [result dt c]
                    (if dt
                      (-> result
                          (update-in [:datetime] conj dt)
                          (update-in [:count] conj c))
                      result))]

    (loop [datetimes datetime
           counts count
           rounded-last nil
           count-last 0
           result {:datetime [] :count []}]
      (if (empty? datetimes)
        (add-tick result rounded-last count-last)
        (let [dt (first datetimes)
              c (first counts)
              rounded (- dt (mod dt (* 5 60 1000)))]
          (if (= rounded-last rounded)
            (recur (rest datetimes) (rest counts) rounded (+ count-last c) result)
            (recur (rest datetimes) (rest counts) rounded c (add-tick result rounded-last count-last))))))))
```